# Radiation of an electron around a nucleus

Tags: electrons, radiation

As far as I know, a electromagnetic field can be generated by a variable magnetic field.

The other thing I know is that, before the Bohr Hydrogen atom, the problem related to electrons around nuclei was that an electron rotating around a nucleus should have lost energy through radiation.

Since the magnetic field produced by a coil is of the form: $B=\frac{\mu_0 i}{2R}$, why should have been radiation? Isn't the magnetic field produced by an electron constant?

Comment: what do you mean with "Ins't the magnetic field produced by an electron constant?" In particular I don't understand at all what you mean with "electron constant".

Comment: I mean that, since $B$ depends on current and radius, and these 2 quantities are constant for an electron around a nucleus, the magnetic field produced ad distance $R_1$ is constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that if you imagine an electron in a circular orbit and you imagine that this is equivalent to a continuous current in a circular coil or loop, that that would only produce static fields, including the static B-field you mention. And obviously, that would not radiate.

The problem is that, at least in the classical, pre-QM world, you can't really replace a single, point-like electron going in circles with an equivalent loop current.

Of course, if you assume a minimal amount of QM at the outset, then that might be a good, rough starting approximation for some semi-classical problems (like finding a good order-of-magnitude estimate for the magnetic moment of some hydrogen atom with the electron excited to the 2p state), but in the purely classical world, an electron in a circular orbit is not the same as a continuous current in a loop. It's a charge moving around, accelerating (towards the nucleus), with time-varying electric and magnetic fields.

And, even in a zero angular-momentum state, the electron, classically, would still be bouncing back-and-forth from one side to the other, in a linear orbit that passed right through the nucleus (nevermind how it does that, classically). And that, too, would have time-varying electric and magnetic fields.

So in both cases, classically, the electron would radiate.

Comment: I can't see the difference between an electron in a circular orbit and a continuous current in a loop. Classically, what's the difference? The current in a loop also feels the centripetal acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

In the classical picture, the electron is in a circular orbit, hence accelerating, and therefore should emit radiation. Are you asking why that doesn't happen? If so, the answer is that the classical picture has been replaced with quantum mechanics - the electron is not orbiting the nucleus like a planet around the sun but is described by a probability wave function. Light is emitted when an electron drops from one energy level to a lower one.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent paradox essentially boils down to the limits of classical electromagnetic theory. In classical electromagnetism, light is a wave and just that. Charged particles such as electrons radiate under acceleration in accordance with the Larmor formula

$$ P = \frac{q^2 {\dot v}^2}{6\pi\epsilon_0c^3}$$

where $q$ is the charge and $\dot v$ is the charge's acceleration. With that in mind, if we think of an electron in orbit around a nucleus, it undergoes a constant centripetal acceleration that should cause it to emit Larmor radiation. The radiation steals its mechanical energy and should lead it to decay towards the nucleus in a very short timescale.

This prediction clearly fails. Quantum mechanics instead posits that an electron is not a classical particle in circular orbit of the nucleus - it is a quantum particle (exhibiting wave- and particle- like behavior) that has quantized energy levels around the nucleus and spatially distributed in space. (Think, the electron cloud).

In this consideration, the electron occupies a probability distribution around the nucleus. The total electron charge $-e$ is split into $N$ elements. Thus the Larmor power radiated goes as $$P \propto \left(\frac{e}{N}\right)^2$$ for any one charge element. Since the charge is distributed into infinitely many elements, $N\rightarrow\infty$ and we have $P\rightarrow0$.

The quantum treatment of an electron resolves the paradox. The effective magnetic field produced by the Bohr orbit (that you reference) is not relevant to the paradox of Larmor radiation and the atomic lifetime.

Comment: The magnetic field produced by an electron around a nucleus isn't the one I wrote in the question? Wich is constant?